# Complex join on table column with values that reference foreign keys in two other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

is it possible to get data from table that has values that reference two other tables (values like user_id and group_id)?

I'm working in Oracle 11gR2
The problem lies in table t3_access, column auth_id. Here is the sql fiddle for a clearer understanding: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6dd7/5

The result set should look like this:

```
user_id|name |pwd_|usr_opts    |group_id|conn_opt|cl_name |gr_name   |access
Peter | bla1 | ok | restricted | group1 | normal | class1 | profile1 | read
Peter | bla1 | ok | restricted | group2 | normal | class1 | profile2 | read
George| bla3 | ok | normal     | group2 | special| class2 | profile2 | execute
George| bla3 | ok | normal     | group2 | special| class1 | profile2 | read
Danny | bla4 |lock| special    | group2 | normal | class1 | profile2 | read
John  | bla5 | ok | normal     | group2 | normal | class4 | profile4 | none
John  | bla5 | ok | noraml     | group3 | normal | class3 | profile3 | update
```

And I have tried two kinds of select:

```
select t2_connections.*, t3_access.*
from t2_connections
join t3_access ON t2_connections.group_id = t3_access.auth_id 
where group_id IN (select auth_id from t3_access where auth_id like 'GROUP%')
UNION
select t2_connections.*, t3_access.*
from t3_access
join t2_connections ON t3_access.auth_id = t2_connections.user_id
where auth_id IN (select auth_id from t3_access where user_id like 'George' or auth_id like 'Danny' or auth_id like 'Peter' or auth_id like 'John' );
```

and this:

```
select t1_users.user_id, t1_users.name, t1_users.pwd_opts, t1_users.usr_opts,
       t2_connections.group_id, t2_connections.conn_opts, t3_access.class_name, t3_access.gr_name,
       t3_access.access
from t2_connections
join t1_users on t2_connections.user_id = t1_users.user_id
join t4_groups on t2_connections.group_id = t4_groups.group_id
join t3_access on t2_connections.group_id = t3_access.auth_id
where exists (select * from t3_access where t3_access.auth_id = t2_connections.user_id);
union 
select t1_users.user_id, t1_users.name, t1_users.pwd_opts, t1_users.usr_opts,
       t2_connections.group_id, t2_connections.conn_opts, t3_access.class_name, t3_access.gr_name,
       t3_access.access
from t2_connections
join t1_users on t2_connections.user_id = t1_users.user_id
join t4_groups on t2_connections.group_id = t4_groups.group_id
join t3_access on t2_connections.group_id = t3_access.auth_id
where exists (select * from t3_access where t3_access.auth_id = t2_connections.group_id);
```

any help/query/advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Are you stuck in this table structure or can you modify it?

Comment: I'm stuck with it unfortunately, it's a user access logging system designed long long time ago and my task is to get all the users that connected with their user_id or if a user is connected with his group_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should pull the information you are after:

```
select distinct t1.user_id, t1.name, t1.pwd_opts, t4.group_id,t2.conn_opts, t3.class_name, t3.access
from t1_users t1
join t2_connections t2
on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
join t4_groups t4
on t2.group_id = t4.group_id
join t3_access t3
on t4.group_id = t3.auth_id or t1.user_id = t3.auth_id
order by user_id;
```

Basically, it just joins all of the tables and uses an `or` operator within the `on` clause when joining `t3_access`.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6dd7/17)**

I didn't dive much deeper into this but my gut told me there are some flaws with this data model.  There seems to be an association between `t3_access` and `t1_users`, as well as `t4_groups`.  The associations between the tables hinge upon the `auth_id` column, which stores a value as opposed to a key.

Comment: very close, but the last row is sufficient, in the output there should not be a record:
"Peter | Peter Pan | Group1 | class1 | Profile1 |"

Comment: the design is terrible :)
t1_users has user_id's as PK, table t4_groups has group_id's as PK, t2_connections show what user belong to what group and lastly t3_access has mixed values where some user connected with his user_id or maybe with his group_id.

Comment: also in the output there should be a column t3_access.gr_name, sorry for a late update...
in the output there should be only two Peters
1. Peter (group2|class1|profile2|) and 2.Peter (group1|class1|profile1)

Comment: You are seeing more than two Peters?

Comment: yes, beacause I forgot to mention to add t3.gr_name to the query, here is the updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6dd7/21
the 7.th row is sufficient (Peter|Group2|class1|profile1)
many thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I'm not certain we can get rid of that 7th record.  Peter can connect with `GROUP1` or `GROUP2` so in the `access` table how can we tell how he connected if we just use his name as the key?  There is nothing I see in the data model that allows us to discern that.

Comment: That is my core problem, I was afraid of that. Is there a way to change the model to get rid of him? 
Anyway, you helped me a lot :)

Comment: I think adding the `group_id` to the `access` table would be a quick fix, however it already has `gr_name` which really doesn't correspond with groups at all, its talking about profiles. But with that in place we can narrow it down to a one to one relationship between connections and access. I gotta run, I will be back on later let me know how you make out.